# How do I set project parameters?

Tags: vb.net, ssis

In a package located in the SSISDB node I am trying to execute, I have one package parameter and one project parameter.

I am able to set the package parameter by providing ExecutionValueParameterSet to the execute method. It is something like this:

```
Dim setValueParameters As New ObjectModel.Collection(Of PackageInfo.ExecutionValueParameterSet)
Dim exp As New PackageInfo.ExecutionValueParameterSet
exp.ObjectType = 30
exp.ParameterName = sp.Name
If sp.Value IsNot Nothing Then
     Select Case sp.TypeCode
          Case TypeCode.String
                exp.ParameterValue = sp.Value
          Case Else
          exp.ParameterValue = Convert.ChangeType(sp.Value, sp.TypeCode)
     End Select
End If

setValueParameters.Add(exp)
package.Execute(use32BitRuntime, er, setValueParameters)
```

Now, this works fine for package parameters. But I cannot set parameters on the project level.

I have tried the following:

```
package.Parent.Parameters(sp.Name).Set(ParameterInfo.ParameterValueType.Literal, sp.Value)
```

However, I still get errors that the parameter is missing. If I check `package.Parent.Parameters(sp.Name).ValueSet` parameter after setting it is false.

Any ideas?

Comment: When you're referencing the `ObjectType` for the project parameter, are you still using the value 30? It should be 20

Comment: Ahh, you are right, the value should be 20 for project parameters and I should NOT set the value this way:

    package.Parent.Parameters(sp.Name).Set(ParameterInfo.ParameterValueType.Literal, sp.Value)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the ObjectType. The magic number assigned to them has meaning.

- 20 Project Parameter
- 30 Package Parameter
- 50 Execution Parameter

You can also get an idea of what is available by querying the integration services catalog

```
SELECT * FROM SSISDB.catalog.object_parameters AS OP
```

See also

[Execute SSIS 2012 Package with Parameters via .Net](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/21978.execute-ssis-2012-package-with-parameters-via-net.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @billinkc I found that I should set project parameters on the same ExecutionValueParameterSet but use exp.ObjectType = 20 for project parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Also see this SSIS WIKI page about parameters:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/21978.execute-ssis-2012-package-with-parameters-via-net.aspx